# Палиндром - ошибка

Tags: c++, строки

Программа должна проверять строку на палиндром. Не понимаю , в чем ошибка. Компилятор пишет не хватает точки запятой , проверяю вроде все есть. Помогите разобраться.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    bool isPalindrom (string s){
        string h ;
        h="";
        for (auto i : s)  {
            h = i + h ;
        }
        if (h == s ) {
            return true ;
        }

        return false ;
    }

    int main() {
        string s ;
        cin >> s ;
        cout  << isPalindrom(s) ;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: а у меня всё нормально. Проверьте, может компилятор auto не поддерживает. или : циклы...

Comment: а зачем вы отделяете пробелом каждый `;`

Comment: @Bulson не знаю , машинально , это ведь не влияет на код ?

Comment: @pavel, пробовал в eclipse и в codeblocks

Comment: Работает: https://ideone.com/1a53fh

Comment: Во-первых, так никто не делает. Во-вторых, это может привести к путанице, какая строка кода закрыта, а какая нет. Я понял в чем дело. Откройте любую книгу и обратите внимание, что знаки препинания не отделяют пробелами. Не  `.`, не `,`, не `?`, не `!` не отделяют пробелами от предыдущего слова. Вы же не иероглифами пишете?

Answer (score 5):

Кстати, если уж вы используете строки C++ и разворачиваете строку в обратном направлении, то было бы эффективнее сделать [так](https://ideone.com/aXsYCe):

```
bool isPalindrom (const string& s)
{
    string h(s);
    reverse(h.begin(),h.end());
    return h == s;
}
```